# Login system with mysqlconnector in vb2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have made a simple login code for my program.

On my website i have made a mysql database for the program where usernames,emails,and password are stored , i have queried the database 2 times to insert 2 accounts.

I can login without a problem with the first account but not with the second and the third so on.

anyways here's the code :

```
Dim dbConn As New MySqlConnection
                        Dim UsernameVerify As New MySqlCommand
                        Dim PasswordVerify As New MySqlCommand
                        Dim EmailVerify As New MySqlCommand
                        Dim typeverify As New MySqlCommand
                        Dim lgnUsername As String
                        Dim lgnPassword As String
                        Dim lgnEmail As String
                        Dim lgntype As String
                        'server info
                        dbConn.ConnectionString = "server=*************;UserID=*******;password=********;database=*****"
                        Try
                            dbConn.Open()
                            UsernameVerify.Connection = dbConn
                            UsernameVerify.CommandText = "Select USERNAME from users"
                            PasswordVerify.Connection = dbConn
                            PasswordVerify.CommandText = "Select PASSWORD from users"
                            EmailVerify.Connection = dbConn
                            EmailVerify.CommandText = "Select EMAIL from users"
                            typeverify.Connection = dbConn
                            typeverify.CommandText = "Select TYPE from users"


                            lgnUsername = UsernameVerify.ExecuteScalar
                            lgnPassword = PasswordVerify.ExecuteScalar
                            lgnEmail = EmailVerify.ExecuteScalar
                            lgntype = typeverify.ExecuteScalar
                            dbConn.Close()
                            If ComboBox1.Text = lgnUsername And ComboBox2.Text = lgnPassword And ComboBox3.Text = lgnEmail And ComboBox4.Text = lgntype Then
                                Panel1.BackgroundImage = mpng2
                                Label5.Text = "Succesfully verified user !"
                                Me.Close()

                            Else
                                Panel1.BackgroundImage = mpng
                                Label5.Text = "Could not find user check your credentials"
                                ComboBox1.Focus()

                            End If
                        Catch ex As MySqlException
                            Label5.Text = "Error while verifying "
                            MessageBox.Show("Error when connecting to database|" + ex.Message)
                            dbConn.Dispose()
                            verifying.Close()

                        End Try
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this.

I already was considering using a while loop or something or is there something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for a loop, and you're making life hard for yourself. Remember to always keep it simple.

Simple login code could look something like this:

```
Protected Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SYstem.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    Dim conn As New MysqlConnection("Server=****;Database=****;User=****;Password=****;")

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT userid, username, password, email, type FROM users WHERE username = xname AND password = xpass"

    Dim args As New List(Of MySqlParameter)
    args.Add(New MySqlParameter("xname", txtUsername.Text))
    args.Add(New MySqlParameter("xpass", txtPassword.Text))

    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(args.ToArray) ' You might want to check this, not sure if it needs the .ToArray

    Dim drLogin As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If drLogin.HasRows

        ' do login code here (I'll store user details out the DataReader and redirect)
        dr.Read()

        Session("userid") = dr("userid")
        Session("username") = dr("username")
        Session("usertype") = dr("type")

        Response.Redirect("~/Members/Home.aspx")
    Else
        lblerr.Text = "Invalid username/password"
        lblerr.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
```

This code gets all the user info you may require in 1 single query (good for limiting overhead on the database). The WHERE clause in the sql means it'll only get a row where the username and password match what the user logged in with.

The `List(Of SqlParameter)` simply stores the entered values for use in the sql. This helps secure the form more as sql injection is much less likely this way. I converted this List to an array here because I'm not sure if SqlCommand.Paramaters.AddRange accepts a List. One way or the other will work.

The session variables are useful for displaying content that is relevant to ONLY the logged in user. You could use the userid to limit results from the database to only get things where the userid is the same as the Session("userid") value.

Hope this helps!